# LINQ to SQL DataContext "Distributed Transaction Completed" Error, but no Transaction is active

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

It seems like the error, "Distributed Transaction Completed. Either Enlist this session in a new transaction of the NULL transaction," is a pervasive problem with many discussions and varying causes, but after looking around I still can't identify what might be causing it in my case. I am using a LINQ-to-SQL DataContext-derived class to query and update a database, but about half the updates we do are split between direct SQL updates and updates performed via another API in the partial methods for Insert, Update and Delete on the DataContext. When we detect that both SQL and third party updates will be occurring, we create a new TransactionScope object with the "TransactionScopeOption.Required" option, then retrieve the ambient transaction and enlist the third party API in the same distributed transaction.

This seems to have been working relatively reliably in most cases. But there is a rare and hard-to-reproduce error that sometimes occurs. When an expected (user) error occurs during SubmitChanges due to some failed validation during a partial method on the DataContext, our code will dispose of the TransactionScope without calling Complete on it and report the error to the user. If the same transaction is attempted again, sometimes it works, but other times we get the error reported *and* the unexpected DTC error.

The really bizarre part is that if I do a Debug.WriteLine to check on the state of System.Transactions.Transaction.Current, then I can no longer reporiduce the error. If I change the code to report the same info to a text file instead of the Debug stream, I can reproduce the error easily. It makes me suspect there's some weird thread synchronization issue going on.

In searching for answers, I stumbled across one topic that led me to try using RequiresNew instead of Required as the TransactionScopeOption. But this resulted in a different error under similar circumstances: "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Open."

I have confirmed (via the debug output to a file) that the ambient transaction is Nothing when I call Refresh on the DataContext, and then somewhere in the framework's implementation of Refresh is where the error occurs in both cases. I'm stumped. Why does it think I'm trying to participate in a transaction?

**Edit:** The puzzle just keeps getting more confounding. I tried the same thing again (still with RequiresNew) and got "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider Error 12." Is there any information on this error 12 that might give a clue as to what's going on under the covers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Internal .Net Framework Data Provider Error 12` is a good clue that multi-threaded access to the non-thread-safe data framework is occurring. Indeed I was able to confirm that the `DataContext.Refresh` was executing on one thread at the same time the `System.Transactions.Transaction.TransactionCompleted` event had been raised on another thread, and I had event handler code that was un-enlisting other members of the transaction (third party API) in there. Apparently trying to do that at the same time caused some confusion that I don't fully understand, but which is easily avoided by ensuring that the two threads cannot interact with the connection/transaction at the same time. I recommend the use of `SyncLock` (VB.NET), `lock` (C#) or `Threading.Monitor.Enter` and `Threading.Monitor.Exit` to assist in ensuring that multiple threads avoid accessing the data provider at the same time.